# Как поменять значение переменной через нажатие клавиши на клавиатуре? NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Как поменять значение переменной через нажатие клавиши на клавиатуре? NodeJS
Или как сделать так, чтобы document обнаружился[image: введите сюда описание изображения] в NodeJS, без использования html

Comment: А где вы хотите это использовать? Если у вас сервер на node.js, то логично, документа там нет.

Comment: я понимаю, но возможно ли как-то его указать в node или как по-другому можно сделать изменение значение переменной при нажатии на какую-либо клавишу на клавиатуре

Comment: А что вы пишите?

Comment: Если у вас сайт с сервером на node.js, то о ваших нажатиях только фронтенд узнает.

Comment: Я пишу на js змейку

Comment: А почему node.js а не обычный javascript? Интерфейс на чём?

Comment: ну запускаю код я через node и пишу в его среде, почему-то изначально так начал и вот, продолжаю

Comment: А интерфейс у вас есть?

Comment: Не до конца понимаю что имеется ввиду под интерфейсом
Есть возможность перейти как-то в чат для дальнейшего обсуждения?

Comment: Боюсь, что у меня не получается толком объяснить что я хочу выяснить

Comment: Ну тогда могу посоветовать только перестать использовать node.js. Создайте html файл или он у вас уже есть, тогда не создавайте, подключите к нему js файл и перенесите туда код. html и будет document

Comment: Чат... А как его создавать? Иногда высвечивается, создать чат, а сейчас нет

Comment: Интерфейс - это то, что вы видите имеется в виду. Где змейка ползает

Answer (score 0):

В `NodeJS` нет никакого `document`, это браузерный `API`.

Существуют пакеты вроде [`keypress`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keypress), которые решают вашу проблему.

Comment: А почему NodeJS и API вы подсветили как код? Им больше подходит **bold текст** или *italic текст*. (Примеры Markdown: `**bold**`, `*italic*`)